# CodeIgniter ActiveRecord Subquery Evalulation

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord

I have an application where I want user items to be assigned in a continuous, ascending order, but only continuous with regards to the user's previously assigned item_ids.

```
-- Primary query.
INSERT INTO user_items ( user_id, item_id ) VALUES ( <user_id>, <item_id> ); -- There are more fields, but they are not relevant to this question.

-- Desired item_id value subquery.
SELECT MAX( sq.item_id ) + 1 from ( select item_id from user_items where user_id = {$item_id} ) as sq
```

I have tested the complete query (with the subquery) and the query is valid on the database, but when I use the `$this->db->set()` method with the `$escape` parameter equal to `FALSE`, a zero is inserted every time; it seems the subquery (which is specified as a string) is evaluated before the `insert()` method is called.

Can I instruct the `set()` method to place the subquery into generated `INSERT` query for evaluation on the database?

Answer (score 0):

using it that way will not be a good option / proposition as ther can be parallel queries that can read that data and still get the same value. There can be chances of having duplicate value.

Rather, create a sequence table, store the values of generated IDs in the sequence table. For assigining a new ID, run through the following steps:

1. lock the sequence table
2. select, increment the value.
3. update tne entry with incremented value
4. release the lock
5. Use the updated value

That way you can assure unique value for the same.

Comment: Is there a way to have the database do the evaluation? I'm not sure right now how much work is required to implement the external locking.

Comment: Well you can do it using stored procedure in that case. But the coding needs to be done.